# Robust estimation of the two variable difference

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

Suppose I have two data arrays: `arrayA` and `arrayB`. For each data array I can calculate its mean value `meanA` and `meanB`. Suppose now I define a variable `diff` as the difference between these two mean values:

```
diff = meanA - meanB
```

Then my questions are

1) how I can get a confident level for this variable?

2) how I can get the robust difference value?

Comment: By "confident level" do you mean "confidence interval"?

Answer (score 1):

You might assume, that your two variables A and B are normally distributed. It can be shown that the difference of two normally distributed variables is again a Normal distribution with parameters:

$\mu_{diff} =  \mu_A -\mu_B \\ \sigma^2_{diff} = \sigma^2_A + \sigma^2_B$

(see for instance: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDifferenceDistribution.html)

From this normal distribution you are able to compute your confidence intervals.

I don't know what you mean by a robust difference value, so I can't help you with that. Maybe you can be a bit more specific on your second question.

Comment: Can you please add the square in the $\sigma_{diff}$ equation? It's misleading as it is. Also, you are implicitly assuming that they are independent, which the OP has not stated.

Answer (score 1):

> How I can get the robust difference value?

Robustness is not compatible with sample means because the sample means are so not robust. If you would like to get a robust estimate of the difference in location you can use the median but beware that for random variables $X$ and $Y$

$$med(X-Y) \neq med(X) - med(Y) $$